# Can I improve the water pressure by changing from 1/2" to 3/4" pipe?

Tags: plumbing

My water heater is 40' from my shower.

Would replacing 1/2" pipe to 3/4" help increase my water pressure?

Comment: Is the water pressure higher at the water heater than at the shower?  If not, don't waste your time!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a pressure reducing shower head?  Increasing the size of the pipe will reduce friction losses and result in slightly more pressure - my impression is the effect wouldn't be large.

How much more pressure are you hoping to get?  Do you know the water pressure for your house?

Are your pipes currently copper or pex?  Switching to pex and avoiding 90s would probably do more to reduce friction than simply upsizing your pipe.

Comment: And it will take twice as long to get hot water...

Comment: It may take longer if only 1 but with high flow or  multiple shower heads or side bar sprays , no multiple heads a larger supply is needed !

Comment: @LeeSam mass flow rate won’t change just velocity in larger pipe will go down.

Comment: @SolarMike It will take longer to empty a 3/4” line than a 1/2” line when you turn that one shower valve on. There will be a lot more water that has to go through that shower head before any hot water from the hot water tank reaches that shower.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, the pressure is not related to pipe size. The flow is most certainly related to pipe size. Going from 1/2 to 3/4 inch pipe is a huge flow increase. But most showers with one or even two heads won't tax the supply from one properly functioning 1/2 inch pipe. If you have three or more shower heads running, the flow may reduce some. I'm betting that changing pipe won't do anything. You either have poor flow to the heater, or the heater is mineralized enough that the flow is obstructed. If you have hard water and a 30 year old heater, I'm betting it's time for a new heater. I'd also bet that it seems to run out of hot water too soon and makes popping or boiling noises when the water is heating.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, yes you will get a slightly improved flow with the larger pipe. If you are looking for a good but inexpensive shower head buy a Delta model 52650-PK for about $15.00 from Home Depot, Lowes, Or almost any Plumbing supply store. I tried 1 and liked it so much I bought 3 more. I have 3 showers and have an extra for a spare.  My 2 cents